# "link" and "do" in Phoenix/Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

This cause an exception:

```
          <%= link("", to: some_path(@conn, :show, 123), class: "some_class") do %>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
            Read.....
          <% end %>
```

which is

```
 ** (CompileError) : undefined function link/3
```

Whereas this doesn't

```
link("title", to: some_path(@conn, :show, 123), class: "some_class")
```

How to fix the 1st example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you where giving an empty string and a `do end` block. Try this

```
  <%= link to: some_path(@conn, :show, 123), class: "some_class" do %>
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></i>
    Read.....
  <% end %>
```